# Correct phrase for “Chain of equations”

Tags: mathematics

In math, one often writes

> *a = b = c = d*

to prove that *a=d*. How is such a sequence of equations called in English?

In German, there is “Gleichungskette”, but the direct translation “Chain of equation” is not found very often by Google, hence my query.

Comment: "Chain of equation" would be confusing. It made me first think of a series of equations leading to a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**continued equality** (mathematics)

An expression in which three or more quantities are set equal by means of two or more equality signs.

McGraw-Hill Dictionary of Scientific & Technical Terms, 6E, Copyright © 2003 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

Comment: Strange that I have never heard of it. But thanks!

Comment: http://www.xdict.net/en/continued%20equality/ translates it as "Fortsetzung Gleichstellung."

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: You're welcome. I've never heard of it either, but it's actually in the cited dictionary :)

Comment: @rajah9: I know nothing about German, but it seems xdict.net has just done a word-for-word translation for the terminology.

Comment: @rajah9 they, that translation is rubbish.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner,  „traduttore, traditore.“ *Gleichungskette* is clearly superior. In this case, especially, the (mechanical) "translator (is a) traitor."

Comment: -1: I don't think this is the usual term; I think that would be "chain of equalities". Look at this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chain+of+equalities%2Ccontinued+equality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchain%20of%20equalities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinued%20equality%3B%2Cc0). "Chain of equalities" is slightly more frequent than "continued equality". But if you look at the actual examples, 80% of the instances of "continued equality" have nothing to do with mathematics, while most of the ones for "chain of equalities" do.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [Transitive Property of Equality](http://www.mathwords.com/t/transitive_property.htm). The page uses your example (without the *d*).

Comment: Joachim is not asking about the name of the property that his sequence demonstrates (ie. that a=d because of the chain of equations); rather, he is asking about the name for the sequence of equations itself (`a=b=c=d`).